# Could inhibition of progerin formation slow the rate at which a body ages?

Tags: human-biology, senescence

According to wikipedia, [progerin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progerin) is activated in senescent cells. The protein itself is known to be the cause of a rare affliction '[progeria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progeria)' - a disease marked by accelerated aging of the body. This disease is not accompanied by neurodegeneration.

- Is progerin the key factor in the aging process?
- If yes, could inhibition of progerin formation control the rate at which a body ages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Progeria (and related) syndromes are essentially a collection of 'accelerated aging' phenotypes caused by single mutations; Progerin is a shortened version of the protein Lamin A, and is therefore *not* found in individuals without a loss-of-function mutation in the *LMNA* gene ([the wiki page you reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progerin)). As far as we are aware these genes do not 'cause' aging in individuals without the mutations.

*LMNA* is a normal component of the [nuclear lamina](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_lamina) (a structure inherent to the nucleus). [This review](http://www.goldmanlab.northwestern.edu/articles/MattoutCOCB2006.pdf) discusses the various diseases associated with mutations in this gene, some of which present 'accelerated aging' phenotypes. However, as far as I know, there is limited evidence to suggest that *LMNA*, or indeed any Lamina associated protein, is involved in 'normal aging'. A [recent GWAS meta-analysis](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22340368) found a variant in *LMNA* that is associated with longevity in humans, however the association is relatively weak (OR=1.18, P=7(x10)-4), so even if this is a true association, it seems that (as usual in aging research) there are *many* other factors to consider, and it is not a single gene that is doing the aging.

So to stress the point: **progerin has no function in 'normal' human aging - it is a defective protein caused by a germline (or novel) mutation in the *LMNA* gene.**  Accelerated aging is the *symptom* of this genetic disorder, and is not completely analogous to normal aging (as you point out, there is no cognitive decline that is associated with normal human aging).

Comment: Could the LMNA be a catalyst, or a key element in the pathway though?

Comment: A catalyst to what, and what pathway? If you mean aging, there is no 'aging pathway'

Comment: Also note that although the symptoms of progeria resemble aging it is not true that aging results in the same cellular problems (for a start, progerin is not physiologically produced in old age)